# how do you convert graphics to features and then associate those features with an existing layer?

Tags: arcgis-9.3

Say for example, that you have water ties. These ties connect from a home to the main water line along the street. You want to draw these ties in ArcMap and give them attribute values regarding how long the ties are. However there is already an existing layer and many of the ties have already been drawn and connected to this layer. You are told to finish drawing the remaining lines and input the remaining measurements for those lines into the already established layer's attribute table.

After drawing a line from the Polygon (home) to the waterline, how do you relate it to the existing layer so that you can enter its length information?

Answer (score 2):

You should just edit the line feature using the [editor toolbar](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Starting_and_stopping_an_edit_session).  You may want to setup a snapping tolerance for both your polygon and line layers.

If you create graphics instead of just editing the existing feature you will create extra steps as far as [graphic to feature conversion](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Converting_between_graphics_and_features), attributing, and snapping topology.